# Inspector-like binding for data object

Tags: cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings

I have many identical objects called `people` which almost contain only properties like:

`@property (strong) NSString* name;`

I would like to have a panel, inspector style, that would allow me to edit the properties of these objects.

The way I used to do that up until now, was:

1. to have the window controller own an `editedPeople` object to have
   methods like: `-(void)setEditedPeople:(PeopleClass*)people` and
   `-(void)loadDataFromEditedPeopleObject` and
   `-(void)saveDataToEditedPeopleObject` to have all the controls in
   the window send my a `-(void)dataDidChange:(id)sender` message each
   time the user changed some data.

Basically, `loadDataFromEditedPeopleObject` is invoked by `setEditedPeople:` and `saveDataToEditedPeopleObject` is invoked by `dataDidChange`.

Now, I have a feeling this can be down without writing much code. Especially, I would like to avoid writing `loadDataFromEditedPeopleObject` and `saveDataToEditedPeopleObject`.

So I tried adding a people object to my nib, but I can't wire the `@property (strong) NSString* name;` from the people object to the NSTextfield I did put in the window.

What is the right way to achieve my goal (just set a new people object and have it magically been updated) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this sounds like a good candidate for bindings.

Let's start with the case where you have a singular to-one relationship property on your controller (relating to a part of your model):

```
@property (strong) Person* person;
```

You could then bind views to the properties of this property of the controller. For example, a window controller would typically be the File's Owner of a window NIB. So, you might bind the "value" binding of a text field to the File's Owner with the model key path "person.name".

Once you've done that, the text field will display the value from the `name` property of the `person` property of the controller. If you edit the value in the text field, the new value will be set for the `name` property of the `person` property of the controller. Thus, the editing will more-or-less-automatically update the `Person` object.

If you change the `person` property of the controller to make it refer to a different `Person` object, all of the bound views will track that change and update themselves. You have to be careful to only update the `person` property in a key-value-observing-compliant manner. (Bindings is built on top of key-value coding and key-value observing.) The simplest way to be KVO-compliant is to always use the setter method to modify the property. So, call `-setPerson:` on the controller or assign to `controller.person`, but don't directly modify the instance variable that backs the `person` property.

Now, your question referred to "people", which is plural, but it wasn't clear that you actually meant that. If your controller has a to-many relationship property called "people", that would typically be an array. In that case, the contents of the array would typically be displayed in a table view or a collection view. Each element would show some properties of the corresponding `Person` object, and might be editable right there in the table or collection. You might also have a detail view which shows more of the properties of the selected item and allow them to be edited.

In that case, you would add an array controller (`NSArrayController`) instance to the NIB. You'd bind the array controller's "content array" binding to File's Owner with model key path "people". Then, you'd bind the table or collection view's "content" binding to the array controller, with controller key "arrangedObjects". You would also bind the table or collection view's "selectionIndexes" binding to the array controller, with controller key "selectionIndexes".

For a view-based table view with a `NSTableCellView`-based cell view, the cell view's `objectValue` property will be automatically be set to the associated `Person` object from the window controller's `people` array. Individual subviews within the cell view, such as a text field, should then be bound to the cell view, with a model key path starting with `objectValue.`, such as `objectValue.name`.

For a collection view, each `Person` will be represented by an instance of `NSCollectionViewItem`. A prototype instance of that class will be in the NIB. Each collection view item will have an associated view to show that particular `Person`. Each collection view item will also have it `representedObject` set to the particular `Person` object from the `people` array. The view and subviews can be bound to the collection view item, with model key paths which start with `representedObject.`, such as `representedObject.name`.

For a detail view, the subviews would be bound to the array controller, controller key "selection", model key path naming the property that that subview displays and allows to be edited. For example, a text field's "value" binding might be bound to the array controller, controller key "selection", model key path "name" to show/edit the name of the `Person` object that's selected in the table or collection view.

Comment: **Thank you for this very clear reply**. You are right, I meant Person, not People.